# Eclipse CDT code formatting: indentation wrong in classes, and potential problems with lambda expressions

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

I have some small issues with the built-in code style formatter in Eclipse CDT (using Luna 4.4). First, I'd like my classes to look like this:

```
class Test
{
public:
  void foo();
private:
  void bar();
};
```

But instead, I get the `private:` indented as well, so that after auto-formatting it always looks like this:

```
class Test
{
public:
  void foo();
  private:
  void bar();
};
```

As for options, I have unchecked the indentation option "'public', 'protected', 'private' within class body" and checked "Declarations relative to 'public', 'protected', 'private'". Is this a bug with the formatter or am I maybe missing another option?

The second potential problem occurs when using [lest.hpp](https://github.com/martinmoene/lest), but writing this I just managed to reproduce it in a very simple minimal example:

```
int foo[] =
  {
    1,
    2
  };
```

The setting for braces for initializer lists is on "same line", but even putting it to "next line" gives me this indentation (although there is a setting "next line indented"). Could this be an interaction with another option? I basically want to have the braces there not indented at all.

Strange behaviour: given the above `int foo[]`, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and it created the code format I desire (moving the brace to the next line without indentation), but pressing the combination a *second time*, it further indents the braces.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Otherwise I'd maybe create a bug report for this.

Comment: I believe you are not doing any thing wrong. I also get indent bugs when pasting codes.

Comment: @Krypton Ah, good to hear; I had to move on from Eclipse CDT anyway because the (built-in?) parser said there were errors in my code even though everything is correct and built correctly. This seems to be a bug, since some other people already reported it as such in the google group on `catch.hpp`.

Comment: yeah, same thing here, it would seem that "public protected private within class body" is offset from "class" and not the indented brace if there is one.

Comment: This bug is still present in version 4.18.0, but the indentation of the `private:` can at least be avoided by either having a method definition, an empty line, or a comment directly before it.